# Python 3 : getting different number using Reduce (lambda x, y: x + y, eachPix[:3]) / len(eachPix[:3]) vs mean(eachPix[:3])

Tags: python-3.x

I have downloaded the images from internet to learn the image recognition.

i am trying to calculate the mean of an image pixel for each row, but I could not understand the calculation, as it differs from reducing (lambda ) vs mean.  Can anyone explain to me how the output gives two different number?  For example, output from first row: Using lambda and reduce I get `80.3`, whereas using mean, I get `165` .

i have pasted the entire code and output it produce.
Code:

```
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import PIL
from PIL import Image
from functools import reduce

i=Image.open("F:/images/numbers/y0.5.png")
iar=np.array(i)

print(iar)

from statistics import mean
for eachRow in iar:
        for eachPix in eachRow:
            avgNum=reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, eachPix[:3]) / len(eachPix[:3])
            avgNum1 = mean(eachPix[:3])

            print(eachPix),  print(avgNum),print(avgNum1)
```

output:

```
  [[[255 242   0 255]
  [255 242   0 255]
  [239 228 176 255]
  [239 228 176 255]
  [239 228 176 255]
  [239 228 176 255]
  [255 242   0 255]
  [255 242   0 255]]

 [[255 242   0 255]
  [239 228 176 255]
  [255 242   0 255]
  [255 242   0 255]
  [255 242   0 255]
  [255 242   0 255]
  [239 228 176 255]
  [255 242   0 255]]

 [[239 228 176 255]
  [255 242   0 255]
  [255 242   0 255]
  [255 242   0 255]
  [255 242   0 255]
  [255 242   0 255]
  [255 242   0 255]
  [239 228 176 255]]

 [[239 228 176 255]
  [255 242   0 255]
  [255 242   0 255]
  [255 242   0 255]
  [255 242   0 255]
  [255 242   0 255]
  [255 242   0 255]
  [239 228 176 255]]

 [[239 228 176 255]
  [255 242   0 255]
  [255 242   0 255]
  [255 242   0 255]
  [255 242   0 255]
  [255 242   0 255]
  [255 242   0 255]
  [239 228 176 255]]

 [[239 228 176 255]
  [255 242   0 255]
  [255 242   0 255]
  [255 242   0 255]
  [255 242   0 255]
  [255 242   0 255]
  [255 242   0 255]
  [239 228 176 255]]

 [[255 242   0 255]
  [239 228 176 255]
  [255 242   0 255]
  [255 242   0 255]
  [255 242   0 255]
  [255 242   0 255]
  [239 228 176 255]
  [255 242   0 255]]

 [[255 242   0 255]
  [255 242   0 255]
  [239 228 176 255]
  [239 228 176 255]
  [239 228 176 255]
  [239 228 176 255]
  [255 242   0 255]
  [255 242   0 255]]]
[255 242   0 255]
80.3333333333
165
[255 242   0 255]
80.3333333333
165
[239 228 176 255]
43.6666666667
214
[239 228 176 255]
43.6666666667
214
[239 228 176 255]
43.6666666667
214
[239 228 176 255]
43.6666666667
214
[255 242   0 255]
80.3333333333
165
[255 242   0 255]
80.3333333333
165
[255 242   0 255]
80.3333333333
165
[239 228 176 255]
43.6666666667
214
[255 242   0 255]
80.3333333333
165
[255 242   0 255]
80.3333333333
165
[255 242   0 255]
80.3333333333
165
[255 242   0 255]
80.3333333333
165
[239 228 176 255]
43.6666666667
214
[255 242   0 255]
80.3333333333
165
[239 228 176 255]
43.6666666667
214
[255 242   0 255]
80.3333333333
165
[255 242   0 255]
80.3333333333
165
[255 242   0 255]
80.3333333333
165
[255 242   0 255]
80.3333333333
165
[255 242   0 255]
80.3333333333
165
[255 242   0 255]
80.3333333333
165
[239 228 176 255]
43.6666666667
214
[239 228 176 255]
43.6666666667
214
[255 242   0 255]
80.3333333333
165
[255 242   0 255]
80.3333333333
165
[255 242   0 255]
80.3333333333
165
[255 242   0 255]
80.3333333333
165
[255 242   0 255]
80.3333333333
165
[255 242   0 255]
80.3333333333
165
[239 228 176 255]
43.6666666667
214
[239 228 176 255]
43.6666666667
214
[255 242   0 255]
80.3333333333
165
[255 242   0 255]
80.3333333333
165
[255 242   0 255]
80.3333333333
165
[255 242   0 255]
80.3333333333
165
[255 242   0 255]
80.3333333333
165
[255 242   0 255]
80.3333333333
165
[239 228 176 255]
43.6666666667
214
[239 228 176 255]
43.6666666667
214
[255 242   0 255]
80.3333333333
165
[255 242   0 255]
80.3333333333
165
[255 242   0 255]
80.3333333333
165
[255 242   0 255]
80.3333333333
165
[255 242   0 255]
80.3333333333
165
[255 242   0 255]
80.3333333333
165
[239 228 176 255]
43.6666666667
214
[255 242   0 255]
80.3333333333
165
[239 228 176 255]
43.6666666667
214
[255 242   0 255]
80.3333333333
165
[255 242   0 255]
80.3333333333
165
[255 242   0 255]
80.3333333333
165
[255 242   0 255]
80.3333333333
165
[239 228 176 255]
43.6666666667
214
[255 242   0 255]
80.3333333333
165
[255 242   0 255]
80.3333333333
165
[255 242   0 255]
80.3333333333
165
[239 228 176 255]
43.6666666667
214
[239 228 176 255]
43.6666666667
214
[239 228 176 255]
43.6666666667
214
[239 228 176 255]
43.6666666667
214
[255 242   0 255]
80.3333333333
165
[255 242   0 255]
80.3333333333
165
```

Comment: To use `reduce` in Python3 you need to import it from `functools`, `from functools import reduce`. Could be the case that you are using not the original `reduce`

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem - both give the same value in my test. But then again, this is not a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is caused by this line:

```
iar = np.array(i)
```

Numpy imports your picture values, which are between 0 and 255, as `uint8` data, as we can see from `print(i.dtype)` and `reduce` performs addition within this datatype. If you add 255 and 254 in this data type, you get an overflow problem. 
Change this line to

```
iar = np.array(i, dtype = int)
```

and your problem disappears, because now `numpy` and `reduce` use `int64` numbers for their operation, i.e. numbers between -9223372036854775808 and 9223372036854775807. [Read more about numpy data types here.](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html)